# Read values from Detail table of RadGrid Batch Edit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Can anyone please answer ,How to read values from detail table of radgrid, I am able to read using BatchEditCommand from master table but not from detail table while clicked on savechanges button:

```
 Protected Sub radDataEntry_BatchEditCommand(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridBatchEditingEventArgs) Handles radDataEntry.BatchEditCommand
        Dim newValues As Hashtable
        Dim oldValues As Hashtable
        For Each command As GridBatchEditingCommand In e.Commands
            If (command.Type = GridBatchEditingCommandType.Update) Then
                newValues = command.NewValues
                oldValues = command.OldValues
                Dim ID As String = newValues("ID").ToString()
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In your batch edit settings of the grid under that mastertable element, make sure you have set SaveAllHierarchyLevels to true

```
<BatchEditingSettings SaveAllHierarchyLevels="true" />
```

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-batch-editing.html